# MySQL information_schema.tables Table Rows: Accurate for 0 Rows?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I know that querying table rows in information_schema.table inconsistent results (40%-50% variance on certain data). However, since 40-50% of 0 is still 0, will this statement still CONSISTENTLY report all tables where the amount of rows is 0? I've tested it to the best of my ability.

`SELECT CONCAT_WS('.',table_schema,table_name)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='dbName'
AND table_rows=0;`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you come up with "40%-50%" empirically, or is this documented somewhere? All I see in the documentation is that TABLE_ROWS is a "rough estimate".

Answer (score 1):

If the table has never had any rows inserted into it, I can't fathom why information_schema would show anything other than 0 for table_rows.

But I think it's possible that a table that has had rows in it, but all of the rows have been removed (by DELETE statements rather than a TRUNCATE), I see the potential for the table_rows to be non zero.

IIRC from the documentation, you can't rely on a 0 value for table_rows to mean that the table does not contain any rows, and you can't rely on a non-zero value to mean that the table contains rows.